# Creating a primitive ramp in Unity - Not working as expected

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

Using cubes as my primitive game objects, I've created a runway, ramp and player. I expect my player to be flung into the sky on hitting the ramp at velocity, however the ramp stops my player cold in its tracks. I have friction and drag set low. Do I need to adjust mass? Should I use a rounded player?

Here are my object settings:

**Ground**

[image: Ground Settings]

**Ramp**

[image: Ramp Settings]

**Player**

[image: Player Settings]

**Ramp 3D**

[image: Ramp Viewport]

Comment: please post the code inside player controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Collider component, you need to use Physical Material. In the Physical material, enter Bounciness "1"